# buildr multiple ant versions when testing

Tags: ant, buildr, artifact

When using Apache Buildr, the project pulls in `ant 1.6.5` as a dependency. It seems that when testing the project, Buildr uses `ant 1.8.0` and puts it on the classpath. JUnit complains about multiple ant versions.

It is possible to set

```
Buildr.settings.build['ant'] = "1.6.5"
```

but Buildr tries to download with artifact group `org.apache.ant`, while `ant 1.6.5` uses group `ant`.

How should one resolve such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I did with:

```
ANTED_HIBERNATE = transitive([
  'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.2.Final',
  'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final',
  'javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA',
  #  'cglib:cglib:jar:2.1.1',
  'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final'
])
HIBERNATE = ANTED_HIBERNATE.reject { |x| x.group == "ant" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove 1.6.5 from dependencies?
Like

```
 SOME_DEPENDENCY -= ["ant:ant:jar:1.6.5"]
```